# Navigation not working in site collection

Tags: navigation

When I go to site setting >> navigation
In currect navigation, Select "display the same navigation items as parent site >> select show subsites

But this doesnot work as expected.

The navigation of site //abc/xyz/default.aspx should be same as //abc.default.aspx  but its not. Let me know how to correct this.

Comment: What navigation does the parent site use, Managed or Structural ? Be aware that "Current Navigation" means the left navigation (quick links) and not the top navigation (which would be "Global navigation").

Comment: This is for quick link.